# Can I work around a # midway through a URL?

Tags: vba

Basically I am using the following line in my code (which I've anonymized) but the # is clearly joining two sections of code together which prevents me from using the document to scrape elements by class and tag name using VBA.

https://websitea.companyb.com/#abcdefg-hijk/r_date=2021-03-05

Can I do anything to concatenate the two strings which will stop my code falling over or is this a security thing on behalf of the website owners?

Comment: Anything following a # is not sent to the server, its only used by a web browser to link to part of the page or by JavaScript to perform some action.  Can you explain more fully that the problem is?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Basically I am simply trying to scrape the website for some of the data and import it into a worksheet. I have used similar websites and can achieve it fairly simply but when using this particular website I cannot navigate my way past the opening webpage to collect elements from it. I am happy to give the actual website page just not sure because I'm trying to web scrape it anyone will obviously tell me I shouldn't be without paying something to the contributor etc...

Comment: JavaScript is probably reading the #abcdefg-hijk/r_date=2021-03-05 string and issuing an Ajax request to fetch the data in the background.  You can use the browsers Network Inspector to confirm this (look for XHR requests after the page loads)

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and I have now overcome the issue. Not totally sure how I did it but its working so thanks again for the feedback and best of coding to you both.